# Does a line break apply after a form in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

Nothing really to add to the title...

I tried it in Chrome and FF, but not in IE. Does line break apply after a form in ALL BROWSERS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but I know certain version of IE do it.

My fix

```
<style type="text/css">
form {
   display: inline;
   margin: 0px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will always have a "line break" since <form> is a block element.

You can get rid of the line break, and the blank line using CSS :

To prevent just the "empty line", you could use

```
form { 
  margin: 0px;
}
```

To prevent both the "empty line" and the line break, you could use

```
form {
  display: inline;
}
```